# How to dump conftest.c?

Tags: dump, autoconf

I have problems linking to a lot of libraries with a cross-compiler. Is it possible to dump the file conftest.c to a safe location each time it's being generated?

I tried to uncomment the lines

```
rm -f conftest
```

from the configure script, but it continues like it means nothing.

Comment: The `config.log` file generated by `configure` has the contents of `conftest.c` for each test, compiler command invocation and other stuff.

Comment: @ldav1s - While building `mpfr`, I could not find the contents of `conftest.c` in `config.log`, or elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

Check the config.log, it includes the failed program
Something like:

```
...
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libogg"
| #define VERSION "1.2.2"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
...
```

Comment: No, sometimes it does not.

Answer (score 1):

For me it prints the code on failure but to force it I created a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in "$@"; do
  if echo "$i" | grep -q '\.c$'; then
     echo printing $i
     cat "$i"
  fi
done

exec cc "$@"
```

Then run with

```
$ CC=$PWD/cc.sh ./configure
```